# Solving SPARQL query from data

Tags: xml, sparql

I have this sample RDF/XML serialization:
[image]

From this data how can I retrieve the name, URI and date of birth of the youngest person in the data using SPARQL?

Comment: Have you tried to start with a SPARQL tutorial?

Comment: And having the data in N-Triples or Turtle format is more close to SPARQL syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by converting the data to Turtle. This will get you to a format that is easily converted to SPARQL queries.  One way to do this is to order the results and get just the first match:

```
SELECT ?person ?bday
WHERE {
   ?person a foaf:Person .
   ?person vcard:BDAY ?bday .
} ORDER BY DESC(?bday)
  LIMIT 1
```

Another is to use aggregates to find the max birth date and query for the person matching that:

```
SELECT ?person ?bday
WHERE {
    ?person vcard:BDAY ?youngest .
    {  SELECT (max(?bday) AS ?youngest)
       WHERE {
          ?person a foaf:Person .
          ?person vcard:BDAY ?bday .
       }
    }
}
```

The latter could be more efficient, depending on a variety of factors.